# jQuery div autoscroller solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I need a jQuery scroller to scroll my divs with auto scrolling facility. I am looking for something like [**jCarousel**](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/).

[image]

But there are limitations for this. What I want is one which;

**1.** Scrolls `<div>`s (or some `html` elements) and not just images. I may have something like the picture below, to scroll.

[image: Sample image]

It is a text and image combination.

**2.** It should auto scroll contents

**3.** The slider should **MARQUE** continuously and should not rewind to beginning. The slider should not rewind (in the opposite direction) to go for first image/content after the last image/content.

What jcarousel is doing is in autoscroll mode, it shows a set of of images/contents at a time, stop for a while, and then immediately displays the next set. I don't want this and want to autoscroll contents smoothly in a loop. That is, first content should come after last content, in circular loop.

I can provide additional details. just post comments.

Anybody got what I am trying to say and what I want and suggest me a solution?

Comment: Do you just want the scrolling functionality, or do you want the to be able to interact with the contents, too?

Comment: @JeffB I just want to scroll contents. That's all. Bit it may support some format i posted as a pic. The item should support a `href` so that i can use it as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without a plugin with some fairly simple jQuery.

See an example here that I put together for another answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Dxg6/

Basically, the idea is you clone the contents of a wrapper, and then continually move the contents to the right/left the width of the original content and then reset.  Works with any content.

That code even includes hover-stop functionality.  Without that, the code is simpler still:

http://jsfiddle.net/qJZtp/1/